# Can't use OR( | ) in php Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I'm a newbie here. I'm facing a weird problem in using regex in PHP.

```
$result = "some very long long string with different kind of links";

$regex='/<.*?href.*?="(.*?net.*?)"/'; //this is the regex rule

preg_match_all($regex,$result,$parts);
```

Here in this code I'm trying to get the links from the result string. But it will provide me only those links which contains .net. But I also want to get those links which have .com. For this I tried this code

```
    $regex='/<.*?href.*?="(.*?net|com.*?)"/';
```

But it shows nothing.

SOrry for my bad English.

### Thanks in advance.

Update 1 :

now i'm using this

```
$regex='/<.*?href.*?="(.*?)"/';
```

this rule grab all the links from the string. But this is not perfect. Because it also grabs other substrings like "javascript".

Comment: Don't you mean `.*?com` instead of `com.*?`?

Comment: `=".*?(net|com).*?"`?

Answer (score 3):

The `|` character applies to everything within the capturing group, so `(.*?net|com.*?)` will match either `.*?net` or `com.*?`, I think what you want is `(.*?(net|com).*?)`.

If you do not want the extra capturing group, you can use `(.*?(?:net|com).*?)`.

You could also use `(.*?net.*?|.*?com.*?)`, but this is not recommended because of the unnecessary repetition.

Comment: I've already tried this but it only shows me the result from .net

Answer (score 1):

Your regex gets interpreted as `.*?net` or `com.*?`. You'll want `(.*?(net|com).*?)`.

Comment: :(  No same result. Sometimes i don't get any result from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$regex='/<.*?href.*?="(.*?\.(?:net|com)\b.*?)"/i';
```

or better:

```
$regex='/<a .*?href\s*+=\s*+"\K.*?\.(?:net|com)\b[^"]*+/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<.*?href
```

is a problem. This will match from the first `<` on the current line to the first `href`, regardless of whether they belong to the same tag.

Generally, it's unwise to try and parse HTML with regexes; if you absolutely insist on doing that, at least be a bit more specific (but still not perfect):

```
$regex='/<[^<>]*href[^<>=]*="(?:[^"]*(net|com)[^"]*)"/';
```

Comment: plz check the update 1. Using that i Can grab all links with javascript too. that's why i want to use a filter(com|net|TLDs etc)